# I am using ReadyAPI 2.6 and need to create use a parameter in the the JSON payload

Tags: javascript

Trying to add a parameter in ReadyAPI `JSON` Payload that will change on each consecutive execution.

I haven't been able to find any documentation that seems to fit. This is a `POST` request.

```
{
   "payload" : {
      "thing" : "type of thing",
      "thing_id" : "xxxxxxxxxxx",
      "thing_type" : "xxxxxxx"
   },
   "payload_type" : "JSON",
   "command" : "numeric value" I want to replace this value on consecutive executions.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To loop over some bits of data several times you test case should have:

- A "DataSource" step
- An actual request step,
- A "DataSource Loop" step (connected with both data source and request).

You should add some properties in "DataSource" step indicating bits of data that you're interested in, and then include these properties in request by their names. For example, in request body:

```
{
    "parameter_one" : 123,
    "parameter_two" : "${dataSourceName#propertyName}"
}
```

When the test case is to be run, the same request is to be run several times with several data inclusions taken from the data source.